# Routing in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, routes

I am working on an eCommerce application, and I am trying to save users in my database but when I hit the API in the postmen then instead of :

```
res.json({
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      id: user._id
    });
  });
```

**instead of this code following code is running

```
user.save((err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        err: "NOT able to save user in DB"
      });
    }
```

//the complete code of my "auth.js" file is as following:

```
    const User = require("../models/user");
    
    exports.signup = (req, res) => {
      const user = new User(req.body);
      user.save((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(400).json({
            err: "NOT able to save user in DB"
          });
        }
        res.json({
          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          id: user._id
        });
      });
    };
    
    exports.signout = (req, res) => {
      res.json({
        message: "User signout"
      });
    };

///and the complete code of my user model file is as following:

    var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const crypto = require("crypto");
    const uuidv1 = require("uuid/v1");
    
    var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
      {
        name: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
          maxlength: 32,
          trim: true
        },
        lastname: {
          type: String,
          maxlength: 32,
          trim: true
        },
        email: {
          type: String,
          trim: true,
          required: true,
          unique: true
        },
        userinfo: {
          type: String,
          trim: true
        },
        encry_password: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        },
        salt: String,
        role: {
          type: Number,
          default: 0
        },
        purchases: {
          type: Array,
          default: []
        }
      },
      { timestamps: true }
    );
    
    userSchema
      .virtual("password")
      .set(function(password) {
        this._password = password;
        this.salt = uuidv1();
        this.encry_password = this.securePassword(password);
      })
      .get(function() {
        return this._password;
      });
    
    userSchema.methods = {
      autheticate: function(plainpassword) {
        return this.securePassword(plainpassword) === this.encry_password;
      },
    
      securePassword: function(plainpassword) {
        if (!plainpassword) return "";
        try {
          return crypto
            .createHmac("sha256", this.salt)
            .update(plainpassword)
            .digest("hex");
        } catch (err) {
          return "";
        }
      }
    };
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

SO please anyone tell me how to solve this problem while hiting this code to api mongo shell is also opend and mean while i also keep ROBO3T connected.

Comment: can you send output error log? console.log(err)

Comment: Yes, you are covering up the error with  "err: "NOT able to save the user in DB", instead of this just log the error and see what the problem is. Could be that req.body does not fullfil the user schema that has been setup